# Load shortcut then close form automatically

Tags: vb6

i want achieve when shortcut link runs ... the form closes automatically, btw im new to vb coding so any help will be much appreciated, here's my code so far

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Set ss = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ss.Run Chr(34) & ss.specialfolders("Desktop") & "\app\SOMEGAME.lnk" & Chr(34)

End Sub
```

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do? Are you trying to run a shortcut and then immediately close the form that opens? And is the code supposed to be VB 6 or VB.Net?

Comment: i'm computer cafe owner, i decided to make a local site embeded in an exe so users can launch programs via that exe window, and also set it as a homepage at chrome, i can't launch programs directly to it's directory because of uac privileges, so i have to launch it via shortcut link, well your code works thank to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using VB6 (which is what your code looks like) you can close your form by calling

```
Unload Me
```

at the end of the `Form_Load` event handler.

However, you don't need to use a form to launch a shortcut - you can add a module to your project (right-click your project, select `Add` -> `Module`) and then just call the [`ShellExecute()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to launch your shortcut like so:

```
'Declare the ShellExecute() API function
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" _
    (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, _
    ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
    ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Private Const SW_SHOWNORMAL As Long = 1

'Entry point of your program
Public Sub Main()

    Dim sPath As String

    sPath = "C:\app\SOMEGAME.lnk"
    ShellExecute 0, vbNullString, sPath, vbNullString, "C:\", SW_SHOWNORMAL

End Sub
```

To make this work, set the `Startup Object` under Project Properties to `Sub Main`.

Using this approach, you don't have a form - your program just runs from the command-line (or from its own shortcut). It's generally better not to create / show a form if your program doesn't need it since forms use extra resources.

With that said, you should try using VB.Net or C# to write programs for Windows - VB6 is old technology without support and it can't handle a number of new technologies. If you don't already know VB6 there's little point in learning it now - your time could be put to much better use by learning VB.Net / C#.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply it's perfectly working now now i just need to test it in win7 like you said vb6 is too old and win7 is a new tech, i tested it on xp and it just works fine thanks again.